# What is the meaning of the line Send the duly filled typed application form

Tags: sentence, sentence-meaning

I have a form given by the employer which has the name, qualification, sex, and such stuff and in the advertisement, there is a line given below. Is that mean I should type the details using the computer or fill the details using the pen.

```
Send the duly filled typed application form by post.
```

Comment: Hello Paulson, welcome to EL&U. Has the form been given to you as a piece of paper or was it given to you digitally, perhaps as an attachment to an email?

Comment: @BoldBen, Hi, It is a job advertisement in the newspaper and the form has to be downloaded from the website provided in the advertisement.

Comment: What causes your doubt? Just fill in neatly with a pen since it is a form. If not, get the entire form typed where you can fill your personal details 'typed'. If the form has an emblem of so, doesn't matter, but if possible the emblem can be googled and pasted in the form to look similar.

Comment: If it specifies _typed_, they obviously don't want handwriting.

Comment: Is the downloaded form in an editable format (for instance a Word .doc or .docx) or is it a pdf or image file like a .jpg. If it's editable you can fill it in on your computer (if you have suitable software) print it out, sign it presumably, and post it off. If it's a pdf or image you'll have to fill it in by hand unless you've got a typewriter you can wind it into. I do think that the company may be using 'typed' to mean 'printed'. In other words they want you to submit a hard copy, not email the form to them.